# Jumping of animation on empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
     <span class="button"></span>
     <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
  $('.element').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
  $('.element').removeClass('active');
});
$('.element').on('mouseenter', function () {
  $('.element').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
  $('.element').removeClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4p98cwb/1/

When you hover on the black element the blue one enters the screen. After that if you hover for a sec on empty space the blue one starts to escape the screen, but if you hover fast on the empty space that it occupied before two things might happen:
1. The blue one returns fully shown on screen
or
2. Jumps once or twice and proceeds to leave the screen

The same happens on hover and mouseover events as well. Why is this happening and is there a way around this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get around any issues with JS is to just let CSS take care of it. If you add this to the `:hover` state it will work:

```
.button:hover + .element,
.element:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);    
}
```

See below for an implementation. This saves you a ton of JS as well.

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
}
.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 500px;
    height: 630px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(630px);
    transform: translateX(630px);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;    
}
.button:hover + .element,
.element:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="button"></span>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

### Update

The reason this is happening is because the element itself is still occupying the same space. This has to do with translation not actually moving the element, but transforming it. Once you move your cursor off any of the activatable elements, it will retract, but as it's animating it still occupies that same space, making it possible to hover on that space and retrigger the animation. I believe it's because this transform is only fully applied after completing the animation. Let's test this theory:

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
}
.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 500px;
    height: 630px;
    background: blue;
    right: -100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;    
}
.button:hover + .element,
.element:hover {
    right: 0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="button"></span>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

In this one we are simply using `absolute` positioning and the issue goes away, meaning that the `tranform` is actually causing the element to still occupy the same space. Until animation concludes.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm still getting the problem behaviour described (using Chrome). Might be an issue with how hover events are actually handled while an element is undergoing a CSS transition.

Comment: Ah wait I just understood. Let me explain.. (in post - hang on...)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and sadly confirming my hypothesis! :D I was thinking about somehow tricking the browser so that the animation would work with translate, but unfortunately it can't be. Still it's a good news that the absolute positioning works differently. Cheers!